# Blender: black patterns on my rendered model

Tags: blender

When I render my model these black lines/patterns appear all over it.
I tried recalculating normals, deleted doubles, and checked for extra faces, but everything seems alright.

Other models that I created from the same base model are ok, so I really don't know where the problem comes from. In the picture they also have th same material so it's not that either.

The two rendered models side by side:

[image]

Anyone have an idea of how I can fix this?

Here's the Bleder project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpDNymtcCWtBQTj1qoA3sKUWtzl_fJsV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That looks like a normals problem. Did you check https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html

Comment: Looks like [z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21216/935) which is caused by overlapping faces.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you have double mirror modifier in second mesh, remove one of them